# Как отсортировать list b, по образцу с list a , используя Python 2.7

Tags: python

Как отсортировать list b, по образцу с list a, недостающие значение в list b, заменить значениями с list c? Размер list b должен быть такой же как размер list a.

```
# Sort list b based on list a, 
# any missing values to replace by value from list c, 
# result shoul be: [0, 'a', 1, 1, 1,'ee',1]

a = [0,'a',44,22,1,'ee', '59f90ff0']
b = ['ee',0,'a']
c = [1]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if len(a)>len(b):
        b.append(c[0])
d = sorted(b, key=lambda x: a.index(x))

result = [0, 'a', 1, 1, 1, 1, 'ee']
```

Comment: а вот это 59f90ff0 куда делось?

Comment: a лист с может иметь несколько значений?

Comment: Результат должен быть такой : d= [0, 'a', 1, 1, 1,'ee',1]
В list c могут быть любые значение и любой размер

Comment: У меня результат получается: d = [0, 'a', 1, 1, 1, 1, 'ee']

Comment: а у меня в ответе, как надо :D

Comment: Так вы мне ее и решили ! Спасибо !

Answer (score 1):

в вашей постановке задачи, ничего сортировать не надо

```
a = [0,'a',44,22,1,'ee', '59f90ff0']
b = ['ee',0,'a']
c = [1]

result = [x if x in b else c[0] for x in a] # [0, 'a', 1, 1, 1, 'ee', 1]
```

в случае листа с произвольной длины

```
result = []
i = 0
for x in a:
  if x in b:
    result.append(x)
  else:
    result.append(c[i])
    i = (i+1) % len(c)

print(result)
```